# Reading latest received sms in Android

Tags: android, sms

i saw duplicates of this question. In all the questions, they specified to read all the sms from inbox.

What i want is just to read the latest received sms.

```
Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
for (int i=0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
            // Convert Object array
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            // Sender's phone number
            str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress() + " : ";
            // Fetch the text message
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();                
            str += "\n";
        }
```

It is extracting all the messages, So which one of the below codes do i need to use to fetch latest sms, ( I removed 'for' loop in below code )

> 1

```
msgs[0] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);
```

> 2

```
msgs[0] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[msgs.length-1]);
```

---

**Question 1 :** In above two codes, which one will give me latest message, fetching pdus[0] **(1)** or pdus[msg.length-1] ) **(2)**

**Quetion 2 :** In my code, i am going to read latest sms and search for particular key word and do corresponding action.

When i receive 2 sms at the same time (Say **SMS1 & SMS2**) . My **keyword** is present in **SMS1** .

First, **SMS1** receiving and after one or two second **SMS2** is receiving, so what my doubt is whether my code **will read SMS1 fastly and move to read SMS2** or it will **skip SMS1 when SMS2 received** ?

Forgive me and do a comment if i provided anything unclear, Hope you can solve my problem . Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is weird.

The code you gave first will actually fetch only one message .

```
Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
for (int i=0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
            // Convert Object array
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            // Sender's phone number
            str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress() + " : ";
            // Fetch the text message
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();                
            str += "\n";
        }
```

> Question 1 - You must use the above code . It will fetch only one message not all the messages in inbox.
>
> Question 2 - It will not skip